# Hierarchical JSON with tree structure

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to make a tree like JSON structure with Java where I have a parent node with multiple children in it and so on. This is my code I have partially done this one but not completely successful to do it ..here is the output I need

```
{
    "name": "Culture", 
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Salary"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Work", 
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Effort"
                }, 
                {
                    "name": "trust"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but what I am generating is

```
{"name":"Culture",[{"name":"Salary"},{"name":"Work"},{"name":"Effort"}],"name":"Work",[{"name":"Culture"},{"name":"Work"}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParentChildApp {
public static class EntryListContainer {

    public List<Entry> children = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    public Entry name;

}

public static class Entry {

    private String name;

    public Entry(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntryListContainer elc1 = new EntryListContainer();
    elc1.name = new Entry("Culture");
    elc1.children.add(new Entry("Salary"));
    elc1.children.add(new Entry("Work"));
    elc1.children.add(new Entry("Effort"));

    EntryListContainer elc2 = new EntryListContainer();
    elc2.name = new Entry("Work");
    elc2.children.add(new Entry("Culture"));
    elc2.children.add(new Entry("Work"));

    ArrayList<EntryListContainer> al = new ArrayList<EntryListContainer>();
    Gson g = new Gson();

    al.add(elc1);
    al.add(elc2);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
    for (EntryListContainer elc : al) {

        sb.append(g.toJson(elc.name).replace("{", "").replace("}", ""));
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(g.toJson(elc.children));
        sb.append(",");
    }

    String partialJson = sb.toString();

    if (al.size() > 1) {
        int c = partialJson.lastIndexOf(",");
        partialJson = partialJson.substring(0, c);
    }

    String finalJson = partialJson + "}";
    System.out.println(finalJson);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating character strings to create JSON when you can just create the appropriate structure of Maps and Lists and have it created automatically??

Comment: If you want to do with JSP,
please check the below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56911382/3405508

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import com.google.gson.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParentChildApp {

   public static class Entry {

      private String name;

      public Entry(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }

      private List<Entry> children;

      public void add(Entry node){
         if (children == null)
            children = new ArrayList<Entry>();
         children.add(node);
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Entry workNode = new Entry("Work");
      workNode.add(new Entry("Effort"));
      workNode.add(new Entry("Trust"));

      Entry salaryNode = new Entry("Salary");


      Entry cultureNode = new Entry("Culture");
      cultureNode.add(salaryNode);
      cultureNode.add(workNode);

      Gson g = new Gson();

      System.out.println(g.toJson(cultureNode));
   }

}
```

You will get exactly the JSON you are looking for.